# Transact-SQL: Getting ID of Lookup Value if Data isn't Related

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have 3 tables and two are related (Name and Gender):

`Staging(id, name, gender)`

`Name(id, name genderID)`

`Gender(id, gender)`

The data has been "dumped" into `Staging(id, name, gender)` in a denormalized fashion and now I'm trying to normalize the data.

I need to be able to use t-sql to do the following

1. Insert the name from the Staging table into the Name table
2. Get the id from the Gender table and insert into the Name table as a foreign key

The problem is the Gender and Name tables aren't related to Staging so I'm trying to understand the logic of how this transaction should work.

My assumption was that I needed to somehow to an **INSERT INTO SELECT** with some type of subquery, but I'm just at a lost. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need `INSERT INTO...SELECT`. Join table `staging` with `Gender` via column `gender` so you can get the `ID`.

```
INSERT INTO Name (ID, Name, GenderID)
SELECT  s.id, s.name, g.id
FROM    Staging s
        INNER JOIN Gender g
            ON s.gender = g.gender
```

Comment: Oh :) I didn't know that there didn't need to be a relationship to perform a join. I love this site and thanks.